# how to setup your own facebook app

Tags: facebook, canvas

ive seen many tutorials on setting up your facebook app
but i havent found anything that worked for me
best i found is a tutorial in youtube on link below 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxIl4fUIXS4&feature=fvwrel

im not really sure on what im doing sice i dont know much about using php
i do know how to use asp.net and iis

in the tutorial he have a facebook.php downloaded from PHP SDK and index.php

i downloaded the facebook.php
and typed the content of his index.php on my notepad and saved as index.php
both file is found on my //localhost/facebook/firstpracticeapp/

i did try that that path works i put a sample.html file inside that and accessed is on browser using below just to see if it works and it does..
//localhost/facebook/firstpracticeapp/sample.html

now that i know it works i then setup the details of my app

used http://localhost/facebook/firstpracticeapp/ as Canvas URL

used http://apps.facebook.com/firstpracticeapp as Canvas Page

btw i edited the index.php as said on tutorial changing the app secret and app id to what was given to me...

not really sure what i missed but it says on tutorial if i run use my canvas page on browser it should display what is displayed on the tutorial

only thing i get is an error saying

HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

```
Detailed Error Information
Module  DirectoryListingModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070001
Requested URL   http:// localhost:80/facebook/firstpracticeapp/
Physical Path   C:\FILES\Projects\facebook\firstpracticeapp\
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

can someone tell me what seems to be the problem?
im thinking its the php i dont have enough info on how to use it
and i did it differently on what was on the tutorial cause i dont know idea what that phpacademy is for

if you guys know better link which is more detailed please reply with link

btw if you found spaces after http its because i cant post more than 2 links so i decided to put space there :)

many thanks

Comment: Why switch to PHP? You can just keep using ASP.NET. The whole "PHP SDK" is just a wrapper to some HTTP calls that you could use and that are documented at Facebook, or you could use a .NET Facebook library. After a 30-second search, I found these two: http://facebooknet.codeplex.com/ and http://fgt.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

...nevermind, I was using out of date info.

Comment: i see.. so its not because i manually typed the index.php
many thanks for that info.. so for now i need a free file hosting site to host my .php files right? i checked amazon ec2 but since it requires credit card info ill go try other site.. thanks again..